# How to allocate memory for an unknown subclass of an abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and I have one of its subclasses having a member pointer to the abstract class.

I must write a copy constructor and assignment operator for that another class. How do I allocate memory for the member of the copied class?

```
class Foo{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
};

class Bar: public Foo{
private:
    int a;
public:
    ~Bar(){
        ;
    }
};

class Qwe: public Foo{
private:
    Foo *pointer;
public:
    ~Qwe(){
        delete pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is covered in the [C++ Faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/copy-of-abc-via-clone.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be solved by adding a copy (or clone) member function in the abstract class (that is implemented in the derived class). Only the class itself can know how to copy the content of the class, so this is how it should be done.